# Div / CSS / ZIndex - how to overlap pictures?

Tags: css

I have 5 pictures, and I will overlap these 5.

I read a lot of HowTo CSS / Div and overlapping, but I didn't get it at all.

I have a normal 500 width div container as "content" filler.

Into this div, I will have 5 pictures that are overlapping each other.

I try all "position:", but nothing fills what I want.

Comment: Clarify. *How* do you want these to overlap?  Directly over each other with transparency?  In the 4 corners of the container with one centered?  What?  Draw a picture and link to it in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <img src="1.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:10px; z-index:0"/>
  <img src="1.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:20px; z-index:1"/>
  <img src="1.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:30px; z-index:2"/>
  <img src="1.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:40px; z-index:3"/>
  <img src="1.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:50px; z-index:4"/>
</div>
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example with html + Css

http://www.jsfiddle.net/rPAPz/

(*it is basically the same as @Dobiatowski's answer but with added transparency to showcase the actual overlap..*)